# Django self referance filter for version

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have created different version of Template model using self reference field with one parent Template when user update any template i will create new version of previous template.
***Model***

```
class AppTemplate(models.Model):
    app = models.ForeignKey( Application, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="apps" )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    version_ref = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    version = models.FloatField(default=1.0)
```

Now i want to filter template for specific app if one template have multiple version display only latest template. I have done this using looping.

```
templates = AppTemplate.objects.filter(app=app_id, version_ref__isnull=True)
queryset = []
for template in templates:
   child_template = AppTemplate.objects.filter(version_ref=template).order_by('-created_at')
   if len(child_template) > 0:
       queryset.append(child_template.first())
   else:
       queryset.append(template)
```

How can i improve my queryset Filter ?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways you can achieve this. One way is to use `first` method. The `first` returns the first object matched by queryset, or `None` if there is no matching object.

`AppTemplate.objects.filter(version_ref=template).order_by('-created_at').first()`

Another way is to use `latest` method. This method returns the latest based on the given field(s).

`AppTemplate.objects.filter(version_ref=template).latest('-created_at')`